# TKInter Entry is not exapanding along with Main Window

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using the following code, I am having 2 issues, 
1. When I try to maximize the window, the Entry widget is not aligned/maximized along with main window and see a gap between scrolled text and Entry widget. 
2. Second I am trying to set my cursor in Entry widget when I try to open or whenever my app is active but it's not working for some reason. Any Idea what am I making mistakes?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import scrolledtext
class Main:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Main")

        width = master.winfo_screenwidth()
        height = master.winfo_screenheight()

        master.minsize(width=1066, height=766)
        master.maxsize(width=width, height=height)
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)

        text_area = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self.master,width=75,height=35)
        text_area.pack(side="top",fill='both',expand=True)

        text_entry = tk.Entry(self.master,width=65)

        text_entry.pack(side="top",fill=X, expand=True,ipady=3, ipadx=3)
        text_entry.configure(foreground="blue",font=('Arial', 10, 'bold', 'italic'))

        text_entry.focus()
        self.frame.pack()

    def initial(self):
        print ("initializing")

def main(): 
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Main(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: change `fill=X` to `fill="x"`. You should have received a trackback error showing that `NameError: name 'X' is not defined`. If you are using pythons default IDE I would suggest installing something like pycharm or eclipse as they will show you this kind of error before you even run your program.

Comment: On my end your fucus() on the entry field works fine. What exactly is your need for this focus on the entry field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can address the issue of your entry field not expanding properly.

That is because you have `fill=X` and this is not a valid input for fill. Instead use `fill="x"`. I believe your 2nd issue with the entry field having a large gap is because you have set `expand = True` instead change that to `expand = False`.

That said I prefer to use the `grid()` geometry manager instead. Take a look at my below example of how to do this with grid and weights.

When using the `grid()` manager you can tell each widget exactly where you want it along a grid. The use of weights is for telling a row or column how much if any it should expand with the window. This combined with `sticky="nsew"` will help us control stuff expands within the window.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import scrolledtext


class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title("Main")

        width = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        height = self.winfo_screenheight()
        self.minsize(width=1066, height=766)
        self.maxsize(width=width, height=height)

        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(1, weight=0)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        text_area = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self,width=75,height=35)
        text_area.grid(row=0, column=0, ipady=3, ipadx=3, sticky="nsew")

        text_entry = tk.Entry(self,width=65)
        text_entry.grid(row=1, column=0, ipady=3, ipadx=3, sticky="ew")
        text_entry.configure(foreground="blue",font=('Arial', 10, 'bold', 'italic'))

        text_entry.focus()

    def initial(self):
        print ("initializing")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Main()
    root.mainloop()
```

Update:

To clarify on your issue with fill and expand I have updated your code with the correction so you can see it working.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import scrolledtext
class Main:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Main")

        width = master.winfo_screenwidth()
        height = master.winfo_screenheight()

        master.minsize(width=1066, height=766)
        master.maxsize(width=width, height=height)
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)

        text_area = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self.master,width=75,height=35)
        text_area.pack(side="top",fill='both',expand=True)

        text_entry = tk.Entry(self.master,width=65)

        text_entry.pack(side="top",fill="x", expand=False, ipady=3, ipadx=3)
        text_entry.configure(foreground="blue",font=('Arial', 10, 'bold', 'italic'))

        text_entry.focus()
        self.frame.pack()

    def initial(self):
        print ("initializing")

def main(): 
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Main(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you Mike, I made a change which you suggested by changing lower case "x" it did not work. But I took you example which you provided and worked beautifully. Thanks for your time and suggestion.

Comment: @vas the solution was not to change to a lower case x but rather to change to a lower case x that is inside of quotes. Like a string. I can say 99% that is the problem with your entry file not expanding left to right. I would say 100% but every now and then there is a actual bug.

Comment: @vas I have added a 2nd example using your code to show what needed to be update.

Comment: Thank you Mike,  I understood now and Thanks for your valuable time and help

Comment: @vas glad to help. If my answer solved your problem please make sure to select the check mark next to my answer.

Comment: @vas Lots of new users do not know about it. That is why I point it out just in case. Happy coding!